# How Products is order by relation in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, octobercms

How can I sort the products in table1 according to their connection with table2 i.e. sort the products in table1 by example_relation in table2?

Table1

```
| id | product |
|----|---------|
| 1  | pro1    |
| 2  | pro2    |
| 3  | pro3    |
| 4  | pro4    |
| 5  | pro5    |
```

Table2

```
| id | example_relation | product_id |
|----|------------------|------------| 
| 1  | 700              | 1          |
| 2  | 800              | 2          |
| 3  | 900              | 3          |
| 4  | 850              | 2          |
| 5  | 600              | 4          |
| 6  | 125              | 5          |
```

Table1 model page:

```
public $belongsTo = [
    'pro_relation' => [
        'models\Model',
        'key' => 'id',
        'otherKey' => 'product_id',
    ],
```

Sorting section that needs to be arranged correctly:

```
$query->whereHas('pro_relation', function($q) use ($postFrom,$postTo){
    $q->select('example_relation END AS expose');
})->orderBy("expose", DESC);
```

Comment: what do you want to sort by?

Comment: @AnuratChapanond yes i want to use order by

Comment: but what exactly is the result you want? order by example_relation field?

Comment: @AnuratChapanond yes, I want to sort the products by example_relation.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, when you want to order the result of one table from another table then you can use `orderBy()` inside a closure of the relationship to another table.

So from your query, you can add orderBy() like so.

```
$query->whereHas('pro_relation', function($q) use ($postFrom,$postTo){
    $q->select('example_relation END AS expose')
        ->orderBy('example_relation');
});
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'expose' in 'order clause' (SQL...

Comment: I just copy ->orderBy("expose", DESC) from your code, which causes this error.

Comment: I understand it gives this error because the expose defined is not in table1, but if so, how can I do this order?

Comment: I see that you define expose from example_relation, then you can safely remove ->orderBy('expose'...) since we already add ->orderBy('example_relation') inside the closure.

Comment: Since I use a different case structure there, I have given it like this in the example. However, when you do as you say, it still doesn't recognize the 'example_relation' column.

Answer (score 0):

This is work

```
$query->join('table2', 'table1.id', '=', 'table2.yacht_id')
       ->orderBy(example_relation DESC);
```